# Error occuredjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql

I trying make connection between Mysql  and my java program

My system configuration is:

1. Windows :10
2. 64 bit
3. java version: 1.8
4. jar file: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19

My source code:
**DatabaseConnectivity.java**

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnectivity
{
    Connection conn;
    Connection getConnection(String database,String userName,String password)
    {

        try{
        String url;
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/"+database;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection  conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);        
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured"+e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public DatabaseConnectivity()
    {

    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
import test.*;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseConnectivity db=new DatabaseConnectivity();
            Connection conn=db.getConnection("records","root","dics");
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" Error occured"+e);
        }
    }//End of main method
}//End of class Test
```

**I have set my classpath as**

```
>set classpath
classpath="E:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar;";
```

**I tried to run my code**

```
javac DatabaseConnectivity.java
javac -classpath e:\user\java\jdbc\ Test.java
java -classpath e:\user\java\jdbc\ test.Test
```

**It throws error**

```
Error occuredjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
Connected to database successfully
```

Comment: Please change this : Class.ForName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Now it says `Error occuredcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
` @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: Remove it. That line of code hasn't been required since 2007. Your new problem is an incorrect URL.

Comment: which line? @user207421

Comment: Err, the `Class.forName()` line that forms the subject of your question? The one that threw the exception in your title?

Comment: And is your MySQL Server really running on port 8080? Or did you mean 3306?

Comment: After I fixed classpath error. It showed another error. Which was due to port Number. @user207421

Comment: How can I improve my question @user207421

Comment: I haven't said anything about your question needing improvement, but, since you ask, when you get an exception you should always show the complete stack trace.

Comment: My question was closed anyway. It is bad for stackoverflow reputation. My efforts were pointless. @user207421

Comment: Your question was closed because it was caused by your typos, first in the class name and secondly where you put 8080, which is a Tomcat port, instead of 3306, which is the MySQL port. It would also have worked if you had just left the port number out. I don't know why you think closing your question because of your typo is bad for StackOverflow's reputation, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few problems.

1. The problem was when I set classpath by environment variables. And pass -classpath variable it overrides the default classpath environment variable.

**So add jar file path to classpath option passed with java.exe**

2. Class.forName() is not used anymore in mysql(mysql-connector-java-8.0.19). I 
   don't know why?

**Source code:**

**E:\user\java\jdbc\test\DatabaseConnectivity.java**

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnectivity
{
    Connection conn;
    Connection getConnection(String database,String userName,String password)
    {

        try{
        String url;
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+database;
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);        
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("In Class DatabaseConnectivity Error occured"+e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public DatabaseConnectivity()
    {

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }

}
```

**E:\user\java\jdbc\test\Test.java**

```
package test;
import java.sql.*;
import test.*;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseConnectivity db=new DatabaseConnectivity();
            Connection conn=db.getConnection("test","root","dics");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String table = "CREATE TABLE Employee11(Emp_code integer, Emp_name varchar(10))";
            st.executeUpdate(table);
            System.out.println("Table creation process successfully!");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" class Test Error occured"+e);
        }
    }//End of main method
}//End of class Test
```

3. Third problem, I was using mysql 8+ and my jar file version was 5+. Your mysql version and jar file version should be same. Now, It is 8 as you can see in the classpath.
4. Check the port number of mysql

Login to mysql -u root -p

---

mysql>show variables where variable_name="port";

It was 3306. As you can see in my question I was usnig default port number which is 8080. I must have changed it while mysql installation because some other application was already running on 8080(probably tomcat or wamp server).

**To execute**

```
E:\user\java\jdbc\test>javac -classpath "e:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar";e:\user\java\jdbc\; DatabaseConnectivity.java

E:\user\java\jdbc\test>javac -classpath "e:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar";e:\user\java\jdbc\; Test.java

E:\user\java\jdbc\test>java -classpath "e:\softwares\java\jar files\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar";e:\user\java\jdbc\; test.Test
```

Connected to database successfully
Table creation process successfully!

Comment: And the third problem was?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: 8080 is *not* the default port number for MySQL. It is the default port number for Tomcat. The default port number for MySQL is 3306. Try leaving it out and see for yourself.